# Python Migrate issue while setting up Django site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Django however when I run

```sh
python manage.py runserver
```

I  get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/devopsguy/djangogirls/mysite/settings.py", line 108
    TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Calcutta'
                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I am new to Django and python so am clueless about what I broke.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are opening the string with double quotes and closing with a single quote, you need to use the same at both ends.

Comment: The trace clearly shows the error by pointing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `settings.py`

Find the `TIME_ZONE` property, and fix the double quote to

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't realize such a trivial issue. Silly me!

Comment: @SuryaBanerjee did it fix? consider accepting the answer

Comment: Accepted. Thank again. Solved the issue perfectly.